# Delete files in a directory that have a hyphen in the filename

Tags: wildcards, rm, macos

On my macOS system, I have a folder with 7,000+ images, and need to delete the images that have a hyphen in the filename. I have tried the following commands without getting a response after I `cd` into the directory (I am new to terminal):

```
rm -rf -- -
$ rm ./-
find . -type f -regex '/-/' -exec rm {} \;
find . -name '-*' | xargs rm
find . -regex '/-/' -print0 | xargs -0 rm
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern `*-*` will match any name in the current directory that *contains a dash* (literally "a name that contains at least one `-`, possibly prefixed and/or suffixed by some other string").  This means that you should be able to do

```
rm ./*-*
```

or

```
rm -- *-*
```

to delete all files with names containing a `-` character in the current directory.

In the `zsh` shell, using `*-*(.)` as the pattern would restrict the match to only regular files (not directories, although `rm` would not be able to delete directories anyway).

If these are too many files for `rm` to handle in one go, use `find` like so:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*-*' -delete
```

I'm using `-maxdepth 1` to restrict the search to only the current directory, and I added `-type f` to only delete regular files.

You could also use a (somewhat slow) loop:

```bash
for name in ./*-*; do
    rm "$name"
done
```

Some people prefer "one-liners", and this loop could be written as

```
for name in ./*-*; do rm "$name"; done
```

... although typing it as a multi-line command would definitely be possible in most modern shells.

Comment: Thank you so much for this and for explaining each one. Really appreciate it. This is what worked - find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*-*' -delete